# Include path expression error in MVC4 asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

So I am trying to make a custom login.  I have a login page that I want to check if the username and password match against my sql db.  I am running into an issue when trying to pull in the username in the textbox and match it to the one in the database.  I am getting an error that says  **The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.**  What does this mean?

This is my user controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(Models.User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (IsValid(user.UserName, user.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login Data is incorrect");
                }
            }

            return View(user);
        }

        private bool IsValid(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            bool isValid = false;

                var user = db.User.Include(u => u.UserName == UserName);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    isValid = true;
                }

                return isValid;
        }
```

The error is on the line with **var user = db.User.Include(u => u.UserName == UserName);**

This is my cshtml:

```
@model MyApp.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login Failed.  Check your login details.");
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login Form</legend>
            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.UserName)</div>
            <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.UserName)
            </div>

            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password)</div>
            <div>
                @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password)
        </div>
            <input type="Submit" value="Log In" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

And this is the user model:

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use Include here as Include method is to get navigation properties. If your purpose is to just determine an existing user then use ".Where" or ".Find".

EDIT: ".Find" method need to use primary key to query the dbcontext. If you object is found in the context then there is no round-trip to your database. Use ".Where" will match any predicate you pass into the method.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is incorrect. The `.Include()` method is used to retrieve a navigation property on the model. The error message you receive indicates this, although in a somewhat confusing manner. To retrieve a single user, use:

```
var user = db.user.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == UserName);
```

In this case, `user` will be null if a user with the specified username doesn't exist in the database.